# Sharepoint Document Library Word Document corrupted can not be opened

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, word

In my document library, I have some word documents which I am not able to open in MS-Word directly.
 
When I try to open this document from library I get this error "The file is corrupt, can not be opened". It says it has found some unreadable content in it. After repairing is has removed all the numbering of paragraphs and some formatting.
When I download the same file using Google Chrome, I am able to open without any issues.
I am also able to open its previous versions from version history without any problem.
Can anybody help me how to deal with this issue.

Regards,
Vinod

Comment: Is the word document uploaded to the doc library or created using any document template associated with the library?

Comment: It is created using a template, but this issue happened after 3rd and 4th version, so I dont think it will be having any impact of template and there are other document using same template which are opening fine